# Run unix commands from Java - Auth fail

Tags: java, unix, ssh

I am trying to use this code for running unix command from java:

```
        // Initialize a ConnBean object, parameter list is ip, username, password
        ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("servername", "username","");

        // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a singleton SSHExec instance
        SSHExec ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);

        // Connect to server
        Boolean isConnected = ssh.connect();

            String[] commands = new String[]{"sudo echo 'Hello command!.' > ChenTest.txt"};
            CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand(commands);

            try {
                Result result = ssh.exec(sampleTask);
            } catch (TaskExecFailException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

When i debug my app i get "Auth fail".

I know that my server and username are correct, but not sure why can`t i connect.
I have a key on this unix server ..do i need to add it somewhere in my code to make the connection succeed?

Comment: I dont see port no in code. Which port you are connecting to?

Comment: ssh is 22 port so Im dont think is necessary to prove it.

Comment: can you connect to that server by ssh tertminal?

Comment: I can connect to this server using putty or winSCP.

Comment: What i wanted to know if there is maybe a way to tell the java code i have a key..maybe even add the file path there somehow.

Comment: It might be the sudo command.  Try the echo without sudo.

Comment: I get the "Auth fail" before the ssh.exec(command).
I get it on the ssh.connect()

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24279641/3315914) you have an example with jsch

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting with a public key instead of using a password.

To do that I think you need to configure SSHExec to know where your key file is located.

I'm not a java guy but I think you need something like this:

```
SSHExec.setOption("keyfile", "/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa.pub");
```

Your key file will be different.

Comment: It could be a good idea, but there is a list of IOptionName.<SomeConstOption> and it does not contain the key file path.

It is very strange that there is no documentation for such a thing i have to say.